# Javascript: how to add string values generated from loop

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop:

```
for(var data = 1; data <=10; data++){
    var data = $array[data];
    var allData = allData + ", " + data;
};
```

for eg:

```
var data = $array[1]  value is "apple"  
var data = $array[2]  value is "carrot"
```

when I loop:

```
    var allData = allData + ", " + data;
```

I want:

```
var allData = apple, banana
```

The above add of string:

> var allData = allData + ", " + data;

is not working.

How can I fix it?

Comment: don't redeclare your variable....

Comment: In your for loop, you're redefining/overwriting `data`, which causes the next iteration of the loop to fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
var allData = $array.join(', ');
```

This will turn the array to a string, with a comma in between each value.

or

This is how you can fix your logic the current way you're doing it:
You want to declare the allData var above the loop, otherwise every iteration will redeclare the var, overwriting the previous one. Then you can use the += operator to add to the current value. Also I fixed the loop syntax a little.

```
var allData = '';
for (var i = 0; i < $array.length; i++) { 
    var data = $array[i];
    if(i == 0) allData += data;
    else allData += ", " + data;
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L7ch8u9b/

Comment: Now I get: , apple, banana. Why is there "," in the beginning

Comment: You can add some logic to prevent adding the comma the first iteration. If you follow the logic now though you can see that every iteration it's adding ", " + value. So it makes sense that there will be a comma in front.

Comment: I added a simple if statement to check if it's the first iteration. If it is we don't add the comma

Comment: Ok Thank You. Now if I try to access allData  outside of the for loop... allData  is the last value. eg array[10]... not cumulative of all values.. I need that cumulative value outside of the loop too

Comment: You should be able to use it out of the loop. Are you using += ?

Comment: I added a fiddle. I highly suggest using the .join method for this.

Comment: You should use 'for(let i' , not just 'for(i'. 'Let' makes sure you can reuse 'i' later without issues. If you don't use 'let', it will become a global variable.

Comment: Its works. I was just using a different variable :) Thank You!